# Objectdatasource updating issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectdatasource

Hi all I am creating update functionality with objectdatasource. Actually it was working fine till i have not changed UpdateMethod's parameter. I have two parameter in it but it expecting three parameters. Giving me below error.

```
 ObjectDataSource 'ODSConfig' could not find a non-generic method 'UpdatePagedDataSet' that has parameters: CONFIG_VALUE, configKey, configValue.
```

C# Code:

```
protected void ODSConfig_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
  {
    TextBox val = (TextBox)GVConfig.Rows[GVConfig.EditIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
    Parameter objKeyConfig = new Parameter("configKey", DbType.String, GVConfig.Rows[GVConfig.EditIndex].Cells[1].Text);
    Parameter objKeyValueConfig = new Parameter("configValue", DbType.String, val.Text);
    e.InputParameters["configKey"] = objKeyConfig.DefaultValue;
    e.InputParameters["configValue"] = objKeyValueConfig.DefaultValue;
  }
```

Comment: Your error message says that you need three parameters in your update method. You are missing the CONFIG_VALUE parameter.

Comment: @BogdanRotund: I dont want third parameter. Even in Business logic i have only two parameters.

Comment: Check how many parameters does your UpdatePagedDataSet have.

Answer (score 1):

After Adding the Parameters just add `ODSConfig.Update()`;

After this your code will look like this :

```
protected void ODSConfig_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
  {
    TextBox val = (TextBox)GVConfig.Rows[GVConfig.EditIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
    Parameter objKeyConfig = new Parameter("configKey", DbType.String, GVConfig.Rows[GVConfig.EditIndex].Cells[1].Text);
    Parameter objKeyValueConfig = new Parameter("configValue", DbType.String, val.Text);
    e.InputParameters["configKey"] = objKeyConfig.DefaultValue;
    e.InputParameters["configValue"] = objKeyValueConfig.DefaultValue;
ODSConfig.Update();
  }
```

thanks